# Adding worksheets on workbook_open

Tags: excel, vba

I have an existing worksheet "StudentSheet1" which I need to add as many times as a user needs.

For eg, if a user enters 3 in cell "A1", saves it and closes the workbook.

I want to have three sheets: "StudentSheet1" , "StudentSheet2" and "StudentSheet3" when the workbook is opened next time.

So I will have the Code in "Workbook_Open" event. I know how to insert new sheets, but cant insert this particular sheet "StudentSheet1" three times

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet, After:=Worksheets(1))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Which sheet contains the A1 to be used by the macro?  If this is a Workbook Open event, the worksheets will be added every time the workbook is opened unless A1 is cleared.  Why not a macro that creates the sheets when called by the user?  Is StudentSheet2 a copy of StudentSheet1 or a blank sheet?

Comment: Where is StudentSheet1 located?

Comment: @TonyDallimore Sheet1 in the workbook contains the A1. I will clear cell "A1" after inserting the worksheets. Yes, StudentSheet2 is a copy of StudentSheet1

Comment: @TimWilliams StudentSheet1 is located on a shared folder "//Ndrive/Student/Student.xlsm"

Comment: Does your answer for TimWilliams mean StudentSheet1 is in a different workbook?  The only way I can see this working is if the user creates a copy of the master workbook which contains StudentSheet1 and nothing else, sets cell A1, closes it and opens it to find all the sheets they require ready for use.  This is very complicated.  There are simpler ways of creating the workbook you appear to require.  I think you should add text to your question to explain why you need this complicated approach.  I believe you should tell us your objective and let us suggest a how to achieve it.

Comment: Why not run it on the `Before_Close` instead on a user prompt? That way the user explicitly makes the sheet request, and knows whether or not it has been successful. And if you are going to require users to enable macros then I strongly advise you google "Excel Splash Screen"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Sorry I misread the question, try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim iLoop As Integer
    Dim wbTemp As Workbook

    If Not Sheet1.Range("A1").value > 0 Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="//Ndrive/Student/Student.xlsm")

    wbTemp.Sheets("StudentSheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    wbTemp.Close

    Set wbTemp = Nothing

    With Sheet1.Range("A1")
        For iLoop = 2 To .Value
            Sheets("StudentSheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = "StudentSheet" & iLoop
        Next iLoop

        .Value = 0
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Why are you wanting to add sheets on the workbook open?  If the user disables macros then no sheets will be added.  As Tony mentioned, why not add the sheets when called by the user?

**EDIT** 
As per @Sidd's comments, if you need to check if the sheet exists first use this function:

```
Function SheetExists(sName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = (Sheets(sName).Name = sName)
End Function
```

Comment: Nearly there but the OP wants copies of an existing sheet StudentSheet1.

Answer (score 2):

user793468, I would recommend a different approach. :)

```
wbTemp.Sheets("StudentSheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

is not reliable. Please see this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210684).

---

### EDIT: The above code will fail if the workbook has defined names. Otherwise it is absolutely reliable. Thanks to Reafidy for catching that.

I just noticed OP's comment about the shared drive. Adding amended code to incorporate OP's request.

**Tried and Tested**

```
Option Explicit

Const FilePath As String = "//Ndrive/Student/Student.xlsm"

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim TempName As String, NewName As String
    Dim ShtNo As Long, i As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ShtNo = ws1.Range("A1")

    If Not ShtNo > 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("StudentSheet1")

    For i = 1 To ShtNo
        TempName = ActiveSheet.Name
        NewName = "StudentSheet" & i

        If Not SheetExists(NewName) Then
            ws2.Copy After:=wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = NewName
        End If
    Next i

    '~~> I leave this at your discretion.
    ws1.Range("A1").ClearContents

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    On Error Resume Next
    wb2.Close savechanges:=False
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Set wb2 = Nothing
    Set wb1 = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if sheet exists
Function SheetExists(wst As String) As Boolean
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oSheet = Sheets(wst)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not oSheet Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True
End Function
```

Comment: If you are down voting a post, I would expect you to be decent enough to let me know exactly why you are doing that? Or is it too much to ask for?

Comment: I did not down vote, however the article you linked to is related to an issue with defined names, copying sheets multiple times within the same workbook and not saving. Not just the line of code you singled out which is actually copying from a different workbook anyway.  But even when copying within the same workbook because the code is running in the workbook open event there is no issue with defined names, so the code IS reliable.

Comment: And I don't think your post was worthy of a down vote either.

Comment: Reafidy, I think you just nailed it!!! :) I revisited that thread and rechecked the sample. No idea, how did I miss that!. Yes indeed there were 2 names defined. I deleted those names and ran the code but I still got the error. So I saved the file and re-ran the code and it worked just fine. That was a nice catch!

Comment: I know about this error and I too have struck it before on more than one occasion.  Actually, the amount of times before the error occurs depends on the size of the worksheet, it is not specifically 39/42 times.  However, this error should not occur in the workbook open event because the workbook has just been saved. And be aware, copying an entire worksheet using the cells.copy method can also be problematic and unreliable causing "out of memory" exceptions depending on the sheet size and data.  The better solution here may be to save the worksheet to be copied as a template.

Comment: My last comment was in response to the comment you deleted. Glad to have helped.

Comment: Yeah I had deleted that before you posted and after I had tested that sample LOL.